# Input in OpenTK

Tags: opengl, c#, opentk

How to use Input in OpenTK 1.0? There is not much info around, some classes are unfinished.

What I want to achieve, is to be able to use input not only in OnUpdate function, but also in other classes created by myself.

Comment: This might not answer your specific question but take a look at MonoGame http://monogame.codeplex.com/ an open source project that uses OpenTK under the hood. You can probably look at the source code as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OpenTK.Input](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/OpenTK.Input/).

From there you can get access to `OpenTK.Input.Mouse` and

Some examples from the page include:

To check whether a button is pressed:

```
using OpenTK.Input;

var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
if (mouse[MouseButton.Left])
{
    // Left mouse button is pressed
}
```

To check whether a mouse button is not pressed:

```
using OpenTK.Input;`

var mouse = Mouse.GetState();
if (!mouse[MouseButton.Left])
{
    // Left mouse button is not pressed
}
```

Comment: Note that the above is for 1.1, which is available through the SVN repository. As far as I know, OpenTK 1.0 doesn't have support for this.

Comment: As a side note, mouse does not work with 1.1 build on windows 7/8. There is patched version on github, which is currently the main repo for OpenTK: https://github.com/thefiddler/opentk More info about the issue: http://www.opentk.com/node/3198